# How is it correct for display json object in .xaml file using xamarin c# iOS

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin

I have one API which display meteo data on .xaml file like that:

```
      <Label Text="{Binding Coord.Lon}" 
                   Style="{StaticResource labelResultStyle}"
                   TextColor="White"
                   FontAttributes="Bold"
                   Grid.Row="2"
                   Grid.Column="0"
                   HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"/>
```

[First API object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a1Ady.jpg)

For the second API I try to Binding Data lile that:

```
<Label Text="{Binding weatherForecast.MaxTemp}" 
                       Style="{StaticResource labelResultStyle}"
                       FontAttributes="Bold"
                       HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                       HorizontalTextAlignment="Start"
                       TextColor="White"/>
```

There is no result on the display.

My second Json object look like:

[Second API object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L7d6e.jpg)

How should I call the data from the second object in the .xaml file ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`weatherForecast` is a collection of objects, so you have to specify which element of the collection you want to use

```
Text="{Binding weatherForecast[0].MaxTemp}"
```

Comment: Work ! Thank's bro !